# CodeIgniter: accessing http://localhost/ needs to display codeigniter welcome page

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost, base-url, wamp64

I just installed CodeIgniter 3 in my wamp64/www/ directory. When I access http://localhost/CodeIgniter/ I can view the Welcome page of CI. I set my base_url = "http://localhost/CodeIgniter". Instead of displaying the Welcome page of CI when I try accessing the "http://localhost/", the browser still displays the WAMP dashboard. I already changed the document root and directory of my apache's httpd.conf to "D:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter". The viewing of WAMP Dashboard still persist when I access "http://localhost/" on my browser

Can anyone help me on this?

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter/';


DocumentRoot "D:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter"
<Directory "D:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter">
```

Comment: Do you restarted Wamp?

Comment: yes, many times. I also clear browser caches to be sure that it's not caching issues

Comment: If you've changed the document root to the `D:\wamp64\www\CodeIgniter`-folder, then `$config['base_url']` should just be `http://localhost`.

Comment: Please try what M. Eriksson commented first and if possible, I recommend to use virtual host instead of modify default localhost. Maybe add domain like **ci.localhost.example** to Windows hosts file and use this domain in Apache virtual host config.

Comment: The one that works for me was the AllowOverride All in httpd.conf. It was set to none as default. I just followed an instruction that I found on one of the tech-blog result of my google search.

Comment: Thank you so much for noticing my concern/question